# Variável com varias listas para matriz

Tags: python, python-3.x, matriz, lista

Boa noite.
Tenho um arquivo de texto onde já converti seu conteúdo para listas.
Cada linha do arquivo virou uma lista[], mas agora preciso que essas listas fiquem todas dentro de uma matriz.
Desta forma não consigo concatenar porque existe apenas uma variável guardando todas as listas:
Ex:

> Arquivo contém:
>
> 1 'ola' 'ali' 393
>
> 2 'ola2' 'ali2' 394
>
> 3 'ola3' 'ali3' 395

Então converti para listas, lista = arquivo.split()

> Retorno:
>
> [1, 'ola', 'ali', 393]
>
> [2, 'ola2', 'ali2', 394]
>
> [3, 'ola3', 'ali3', 395]

Até aqui tudo bem, mas agora preciso jogar todas as listas que estão dentro da variável para uma matriz, para então poder percorrer por linhas e índices e alterar como for necessário.
Teria que ficar:

> matriz [[1, 'ola', 'ali', 393],[2, 'ola2', 'ali2', 394],[3, 'ola3', 'ali3', 395]]

Eu acabei fazendo de um jeito que acabou ficando cada linha uma matriz, não saiu como esperado.
As pesquisas que fiz sempre acabam juntando listas separadas e variáveis separadas.
Eu imagino que precise fazer uma quebra de linha ou algo do tipo, mas já me perdi, fico esbarrando sempre nos mesmos exemplos.

Edit:

Olha o retorno deste código.

[image: Código]

Edit 18/10

Consegui criar listas dentro da matriz, porém é listas das colunas e não consigo inverter.
Como posso fazer para trocar cada coluna por um índice, pego a coluna 0 de todos os índices e crio uma nova lista, depois a coluna 1 e nova lista, assim posso pegar o índice escolhido com o conteúdo que desejo.
Seria uma ordenação mas não estou conseguindo fazer.
Imagem do código até o momento:

[image: Código]

Comment: Vc poderia postar seu código mostrando o que vc já tentou? Assim é melhor para a comunidade ajudar vc.

Comment: Olha sinceramente não entendi o que fizeste, aqui não está a retornar quebra nenhuma, imprime o valor total de cada posição, talvez tenha sido o `n` que estava mal colocado, experimenta novamente o código, desta vez tenta simplesmente substituir o nome do ficheiro.

Answer (score 1):

Na pergunta, expuseste o problema, mas não apresentaste nenhum código, para que ao menos pudesse saber onde estás, ou o que já experimentaste.

Assumindo que não sei ao certo como abriste o ficheiro, ou que tipo de ficheiro estás a usar, mostrarei um exemplo que construí, segundo alguns dos detalhes que forneceste e explicarei da mais resumida possível. Provavelmente os códigos não vão estar idênticos, mas não há motivo para alarmes, é fácil de entender.

Primeiro abre-se o ficheiro, e cria-se uma nova array, para depois preenche-la com os dados contidos no ficheiro:

```
#Abrir o ficheiro
arquivo = open('file.txt', 'r')
# Nova array
array = []
```

Depois basta converter cada linha contida nesse ficheiro, em arrays:

```
#Criar novas arrays à partir do ficheiro
for i in arquivo:
    array.append(i.split())
```

E obtemos isto como saída:

> [['1', "'ola'", "'ali'"], ['2', "'ola2'", "'ali2'"], ['3', "'ola3'", "'ali3'"]]

Por fim, basta que percorramos as posições dessa nova array:

```
#Percorrer a primeira camada
for y in array:
#Percorrer cada array
    for o, z in enumerate(y):
        print '(', z, ')', 'linha', o
```

Na primeira camada obtemos:

> ['1', "'ola'", "'ali'"]
>
> ['2', "'ola2'", "'ali2'"]
>
> ['3', "'ola3'", "'ali3'"]

O código por inteiro fica assim:

```
arq = open('file.txt', 'r')
array = []

#Popular nova array a partir do ficheiro
for i in arquivo:
    array.append(i.split())

#Percorrer posicoes
for y in array:
    for o,z in enumerate(y):
        print '(', z, ')', 'linha:', o
```

Escrevi o código usando  *python 2.7*.

Comment: Será que tem algo diferente para usar neste seu código de python 2.7 para 3.x, porque no meu caso retorna diferente, postei uma foto.

Comment: Veja isto: http://imgur.com/a/7tvDy

Comment: Eu tinha colocado zero em vez de 'o', mas não é bem o que preciso essa enumeração, não consigo acessar individualmente. Fiz um teste com teu código coletando os dados do array, ele a cada linha adiciona uma lista nova, mas no caso eu preciso do resultado da ultima linha onde contém todas as listas, vou postar duas fotos. Essa é o resultado que desejo https://copy.com/E8LTnlxJ2FkmgqVV  e está é o retorno do seu código sem a enumeração https://copy.com/l7QYxbb1sE7ymfGM . Desculpa se não estou compreendendo, iniciante sabe como é.

Comment: Edilson, quase consegui mas falta um detalhe, uma ordenação para poder acessar como desejo, anexei uma foto ao post.

Comment: Tinha-me esquecido até, verei o que posso fazer.